# How do you apply absolute coordinates to an object inside a view?

Tags: android

Inside a FrameLayout, I have a view which absolute coordinates I get thanks to a MotionEvent (`getRawX()` and `getRawY()`). However when I apply those same coordinates to that same object (with LayoutParams), the object appears moved (Both X is increased by a little bit because the padding on the sides is very small, Y is increased by a lot because there is a lot of space above the containing object).

I have tried applying the parameters and then substracting the getTop() from the view, but it still gives appears moved. I have also tried substracting the height of the actionbar but it still is quite a few pixels off.

Is there any way to apply those RawX and RawY inside a containing View with precision?

Comment: did you try to use View.setY(), View.setX()

Comment: Yes, does the same as applying via LayoutParams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that even though I substracted getTop() and the action bar height, I didn't substract the bottom padding of the view.

So basically you need to **substract the space above the container view**, the **action bar height** AND the **space below it** (aka the root view's padding) to make up for the fact that the MotionEvent gives you only absolute coordinates.

Retrieving the action barheight:

```
int actionBarHeight;
                    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
                    {
                        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    }
```

Getting the coords:

```
params.topMargin = (int) me.getRawY() - (view.getHeight() / 2) - (draggedMobsArea.getTop() + actionBarHeight) - rootLayout.getPaddingBottom();
                            params.leftMargin = (int) me.getRawX() - (view.getWidth() / 2) - draggedMobsArea.getLeft();
                            view.setLayoutParams(params);
```